# Input search field in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a search field in my application. In my form i have multiple child components, where each component is rendered in a tab in tabset in parent component. I want to implement a search field in my parent component. where, when i search for a value. it should highlight the label and the tab in which this label is present in the form irrespective of the child component and Tab. How can i implement this. can someone provide me an example or an idea how to achieve this.

ParentComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
  <div>
    <input type='search' placeholder="search" (click)="search($event)">
  </div>
  <app-child (click)="search()" [childForm]="parentForm.controls.childForm">
  </app-child>
</form>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
parentForm:FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
  this.parentForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
    childForm: this.FormBuilder.group({
    })
  });
}
search(event){
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]='childForm>
  <label>test1</label>
  <label>test2</label>
  <label>test3</label>
  <label>test4</label>
</form>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
@Output() click = new EventEmitter(); 
ngAfterViewInit() {
  //something like.. 
  this.click.emit({ 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to transfer information from father component to child component you don't need events.
The simplest way I think of it is:

**parent.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
    <div>
        <input type='search' placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]='searchTerm' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>
    <app-child [search]="searchTerm">
    </app-child>
</form>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  searchTerm: string = 'hello';


}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() search;


}
```

and you will have updated variable `search` in your child component and you can continue with your logic from there.

**note: because you are in `formGroup` you need to mark `ngModel` as a standalone*

Comment: Thanks. But i am looking for guidance on how can i match the labels in childComponent with the search input value from parentComponent. I want to highlight the label.

Comment: @rja like i wrote: "you can continue with your logic from there.", using pipe for example

Comment: Or using Directive, Angular official docs building your needs in their example https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I am new to angular. I have seen some examples of using pipes and directives for searching and highlighting. They all are implemented on a loop of items not individually. I do not want to apply it on a loop. I want to apply it seperately for each label seperately. can you please guide me on this. Here is an [example](https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/creating-a-search-filter-in-angular-562d)

Comment: @rja Why can't you put the labels in the loop?

Comment: Hi, I have muti form-field  Reactive form with around 100 Form fields. Each form field has different input , innerHTML, select item, checkboxes etc... for each of them i have a unique label. I want to highlight the label. I cannot make labels in a loop.